# returns the minimum result of taking the tangent of each value from the input while considering only negative numbers

Tags: java

> Write a public static method named q3 that takes a HashMap of type String to Integer  and returns a double. This method returns the minimum result (do not return the original  value) of taking the tangent of each value from the input while considering only negative numbers from the inputs.

This is my code, I want to know if my code is correct or not. Thanks.

```
public static double q3(HashMap<String,Integer> numbers){ 
    double max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for(int value :numbers.values()){
        if(Math.tan(value) > max && value < 0){
            max = Math.tan(value);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(max);
    return max;
}
```

Comment: Please do not post code reviews. You should be able to run your code and determine yourself it it is correct. Why are you looking for the max when you're being asked for the min? Will the first part of your `if` block ever resolve to `true`? Walk through the code yourself first. Post here if you have specific questions about specific issues you encounter.

Answer (score 0):

With Stream API:

```
public static double q3(HashMap<String,Integer> numbers){
        final Double max = (double) Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        return numbers.values().stream()
                .filter(value -> !(Math.tan(value) > max && value < 0))
                .max(Integer::compareTo).orElseGet(max::intValue)
                .doubleValue();
    }
```

Test it, I not guarantee of this realisation correctly works.